# Remove "Folder Open" "Folder closed" announcements without disabling Accessiblity

Tags: text-to-speech, accessibility

I have a Galaxy S3 4G.  I also have a Pebble watch.

The Pebble watch uses the Accessibility service in order to project messages etc to your wrist.  Unfortunately, this means certain other "features" apparently get enabled - like a voice announcement every time I open or close a folder.  Which is less than helpful.  And really annoying.

Is there any way to disable these particular advisories?  I'm leery of disabling all voice apps entirely, since I still occasionally want access to things like turn instructions from Google Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that worked for me.  From [this page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=29100626&postcount=7):

- Go to Settings> Application Manager> All> Google Text To Speech Engine
- Instead of disabling it entirely, hit "Clear Data"

Note: This solution may or may not be permanent (I have a feeling when I next actually use a feature with Voice, it will re-enable), but it's easily repeatable at need.  It's mostly viable for me because I don't use such features terribly often.  If you use Maps every day or whatever you might need to find a different answer.